# Java 8 constructor without parameter

Tags: java

I am programming in Java 8 and I have a simple question concerning the initialization of a constructor without parameters. Is the following way acceptable?

```
class Student {
   List<Grade> grades;

   public Student() {
      grades=new List<Grade>();
   }

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The constructor is fine, but you have to create a specific List, either ArrayList or LinkedList.

Comment: Yes, in Java, all classes inherit from `Object` which has a default, no-parameter constructor. The above example just needs `grades` to be changed to `this.grades` (for good convention) and `List` is an interface so you want a specific type/implementation of it (like `ArrayList` as mentioned)

Comment: List in an interface, you can't instantiate it. You need to choose a concrete implementation. `new ArrayList<>()`, `new LinkedList<>()`, etc. Which implementation you should prefer will depend on your requirements - do you insert into the list often?, does the list need to be thread-safe?, etc. If in doubt, ArrayList is usually fine. Besides that, your code is correct.

Comment: The above comments all overlook that List might be a class defined by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

A few things: unless List is your own class, the above wouldn't work. As the standard Java List is an interface, so you can't use it with new like shown here.

Then: there is no need to have a default constructor here. You can do that call to new right there in the line where you defined the field. Avoid using a constructor when there is only one way to initialize a field.

Plus: ideally in good OOP, you would make that field private, and if possible also final.

Last but not least: read about the diamond operator. That call to new does not need the class name Grade again. The compiler is smart enough to know that.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help. I think I understood but I need to see if it solves my problem.

Comment: @Maxclac Well, you didnt specify exactly what your problems are ;) ... as your question is pretty unspecific (leading to the plenty downvotes you got). You might want to clarify it a bit.

Comment: I could get helpful answers from other users. I therefore assume there is no problem with the specificity of my question.

Comment: Your question received 4 downvotes and 3 close votes. Pretty good indication that it wasn't regarded of good quality. And note "is this acceptable" boils down to other people doing a code review & some tutoring for free. And that is not what this community is meant for.